# egrep regex: having [ and ] or dot in character class does not match

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to match an IPv6 address with square brackets but I am surprisingly stuck...

Works:

```
echo 'files ([2001:450:671d:200::121]:59464).' | egrep 'files \(.+\)\.$'
```

Does NOT match (but I think a dot in a character class is valid):

```
echo 'files ([2001:450:671d:200::121]:59464).' | egrep 'files \([.]+\)\.$'
```

Any other attempt such as

```
echo 'files ([2001:450:671d:200::121]:59464).' | egrep 'files \([][0-9:]+\)\.$'
echo 'files ([2001:450:671d:200::121]:59464).' | egrep 'files \([[]0-9:]+\)\.$'
echo 'files ([2001:450:671d:200::121]:59464).' | egrep 'files \([]0-9:[]+\)\.$'
echo 'files ([2001:450:671d:200::121]:59464).' | egrep 'files \([\[\]0-9:]+\)\.$'
```

Does not work either...

What the heck is wrong here?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53497/7552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first one, `\([.]+\)`, would match literal dots inside literal parenthesis, like `(...)` etc. The other ones don't match the hex digits above `9`, i.e. `abcdef`. There's a `d` in `671d`. Remember that IPv6 addresses are in hex.

You'd need to add those, so:

```
echo 'files ([2001:450:671d:200::121]:59464).' | egrep 'files \([][0-9a-f:]+\)\.$'
```

or more strictly:

```
echo 'files ([2001:450:671d:200::121]:59464).' | egrep 'files \(\[[0-9a-f:]+\]:[0-9]+\)\.$'
```

or use `a-fA-F` within the brackets if you need to deal with uppercase hex digits too.